# FFTW fails to import wisdom but the file exists and can be read?

Tags: c, fftw

My code uses `fftw_export_wisdom_to_filename` successfully to create a wisdom file which looks like some text wisdom data.

However, when I try to open it, like so:

```
if (access("p2", R_OK) == 0)
    printf("File can be read!\n");
else
    printf("File can't be read!\n");

int error = fftw_import_wisdom_from_filename("p2");

printf("Import status: %d\n", error);
```

it fails:

```
File can be read!
Import status: 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

It is clarified in the last paragraph [here](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Wisdom-Import.html) that the value returned is 1 if the import routine was successful.

Comment: How do you export the wisdom file?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm exporting it as: `fftw_export_wisdom_to_filename("p2")`.  
Update: All of this is happening in functions that act on a `struct` which holds my plans and the data and doesn't happen if everything is done in `main()`.

Comment: I looked through the manual pages and couldn't find a function that reports on what error occurred — just the '0 means error, 1 means no error' behaviour.  That makes it hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your problem, but make sure the version of FFTW that reads the wisdom file is the same as the one that created it.

I had this problem, and I'm not saying this is the right thing to do, but I just changed the version info in the beginning of the wisdom file to the version of FFTW I'm using.  3.3.6-p12 is what I'm running, but 3.3.8 created the wisdom file. It successfully reads the file and shows a noticeable performance increase versus when it failed to read the file.